# Передача значения из формы в контроллер Kohana

Tags: php, kohana

Здравствуйте. Начинаю изучать фреймворки php, выбрал Kohana. Не могу понять, как передавать переменные из вида в контроллер или модель. На чистом php через <form> понимаю как, указывается атрибут action и потом переменные в POST или GET массив передаются.

Comment: Из вида в модель ничего передавать не нужно изначально. Вид "не знает", что есть модель.

А вообще, суть проблемы не понимаю. Можете немного конкретнее сказать про задачу?

Comment: Если "на пальцах", то допустим есть <input type="text" name="year">, как передать введенное пользователем значение в контроллер?

Comment: в form написать аттрибут action с указанием адреса контроллера

"foo/bar", например.
В Controller_Foo написать public action_bar(){var_dump($this->request->post('year');} 

Наслаждаться результатом.

Comment: Для создания форм есть хэлпер Form.

Comment: с этим уже разобрался)

Answer (score 1):

Предположим, что у вас форма по протоколу POST:

```
<form method="POST">
```

Тогда в контроллере, в action, обрабатывающем данный запрос, это значение можно получить так:

```
public function action_bar() {
    if ( $this->request->method() == Request::POST ) {
        $year = $this->request->post('year');
        // Делайте с ним, что хотите
    }
}
```